# Stateful user in console application Scala

Tags: scala, console-application, slick

I need to create a console-interface application as todo-list in Scala. I have already created data access layer where I have objects of my database and queries on them through Slick 3. Also, I am trying to create a simple interface using StdIn for reading input in Scala. 
Here is my code for the interface:

```
    object Main {

      val db = Database.forConfig("scalaxdb")
      val userRepository = new UserRepository(db)
      val taskRepository = new TaskRepository(db)

      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println("Main menu:" + " \n1 - Login" + "\n2 - Exit")
        println("\nChoose the operation you want to perform:")
        val inputMainMenu = readInt()
        buildMainMenu(inputMainMenu)
      }

      def buildMainMenu(inputNumber: Int) =  inputNumber match {
          case 1 => enterSystem()
          case 2 => System.exit(0)
          case _ => println("Your input was wrong. Try again"); System.exit(0)
      }

      def enterSystem(): Unit ={

        println("Input you login, please:")
    val inputLogin = readLine()
    println("Input you password, please:")
    val inputPassword = readLine()

    val checkLogin = Await.result(DAO.checkUserLogin(inputLogin, inputPassword), Duration.Inf).toString
    val userId = DAO.selectUserId(inputLogin)

    def changeOutputs(checkLogin: String):Unit = checkLogin match {
      case "true" => println("You have successfully entered"); 
      displayMenu(); buildMenu(userId)
      case "false" => println("Your input for login or password is 
      wrong"); System.exit(1)
      case _ => println("Your input is wrong"); System.exit(1)
    }
    changeOutputs(checkLogin)
      }

      def displayMenu(): Unit ={
        println("TODO List:" + "\n1 - Display tasks" + "\n2 - Display finished tasks" + "\n3 - Display unfinished tasks"
          + "\n4 - Add task" + "\n5 - Delete task" + "\n6 - Mark task as finished")
        println("\nChoose the operation you want to perform:")
      }
     val inputNum = readInt()
    inputNum
  }   

    def displayUnfinishedTasks(id: Long) = {
        println()
        println("User's unfinished tasks:\n" + Await.result(DAO.selectUnfinishedTasks(id), Duration.Inf).toList.toString)
        displayMenu()
      }
```

The problem is that I need to enter into the system as the user and then output, create, delete tasks of the specific user. So here I decided to pass user id as a parameter to all my methods for manipulation. So I tried to do this with this interface, however, I get a runtime error  `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Vector(1)"`
I know that to fix this error I may arrange my methods differently but then I will not be able to pass my userId.

To make it clear, that is how one of my data access layer methods looks like:

```
 def getUserId(login: String) = {
    val queryToGetUserId = (for {
      user <- UserTable.table if user.login === login
    } yield (user.idUser))
    db.run(queryToGetUserId.result)
  }
```

So how can I change the interface methods or the overall logic of user state preserving in this code? I would be grateful for any help!

UPDATE!
Code changed a bit (methods buildMenu, displayMenu). Also, I have created this walkway method in my dao instead of the getUserId. So the interface works but I wonder how I can still change my getUserId method or the way it should be called to pass id into methods like displayFinishedTasks.
Here is the walkaway method:

```
def selectUserId(login: String) = login match {
      case "data" => 1
      case "root" => 2
  }
```

Comment: hi @Cassie, did you consider to use scopt? It is available [here](https://github.com/scopt/scopt) on GitHub.

Comment: @P3trur0 I saw it but did not figure out how to use it in my project. Thanks for the advice

Comment: 1. You probably need to show the `readInt` code since that's where the exception is coming from? Actually, can you give more of the stack trace too? 2. Since you're getting an error on `Vector(1)` it looks like you're trying to parse `"Vector(1)" (which is the `toString` of a `Vector`) instead of `"1"` (which is the string form of an integer).

Comment: @RichDougherty The problem is in this line ``val userId = Await.result(DAO.getUserId(inputLogin), Duration.Inf).toString.toLong`` when I replace it with simple number it works fine. Bu with this line I get an id of the user from the database. That is why I do not know how to replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment above you mention that the following line is failing:

```
val userId = Await.result(DAO.getUserId(inputLogin), Duration.Inf).toString.toLong
```

The exception thrown is:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Vector(1)"
```

This suggests that `DAO.getUserId` is returning a `Vector` instead of an `Int`. Looking at the code for that method:

```
 def getUserId(login: String) = {
   val queryToGetUserId = (for {
     user <- UserTable.table if user.login === login
   } yield (user.idUser))
   db.run(queryToGetUserId.result)
 }
```

We can see this method doesn't have a specified return type. Most likely the return type is `Future[Seq[Int]]`. Since you only want one result you should change this to a `Future[Int]` by calling `head`:

```
 def getUserId(login: String): Future[Long] = {
   val queryToGetUserId = (for {
     user <- UserTable.table if user.login === login
   } yield (user.idUser)).head // Will throw exception if empty result
   db.run(queryToGetUserId.result)
 }

 ...

 val userId = Await.result(DAO.getUserId(inputLogin), Duration.Inf)
```

Here I'm assuming that `idUser` is already a `Long`. If it's not, then you'll need to include a `.toLong`—but this time it should work!

Comment: Thank you very much. It really helped me!

Answer (score 0):

The code above is pretty messed up, can we get a github link or another update?
I won't even format when I throw it into IntelliJ.

and there appears to be unfinished lines: `changeOutputs(checkLogin)=`